# Why using XML to create GUI is a good practice in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am from Java Swing background. May I know why using XML to create GUI is a good practice in Android? For instance, instead of writing the code in (Which makes me feel more comfortable with it as I use to Swing desktop application)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("Hello, Android");
       setContentView(tv);
   }
}
```

We write the code in XML way.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

In tutorial, it states that,

> This structure makes it very easy to
>   quickly build up UIs, using a more
>   simple structure and syntax than you
>   would use in a programmatic layout.

However, I don't really buy the idea, as I feel that creating a separate XML file is more cumbersome.

Can anyone give a real world example (in the sense of Android), why using XML to build GUI is more superior than bare Java code?

**If GUI programming through XML is really a good stuff, why it still hasn't become a common practice among GUI desktop application developers?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using XML layouts has many advantages over Java code. You get easy references to strings, drawables, dimensions, themes, etc. But the biggest advantage is automatic support for multiple configurations. Without changing your code you can have different layouts for landscape and portrait by just having an XML layout in layout-land/ and layout-port/. And you can do the same to adapt the layout to different resolutions, languages, etc.

Comment: If XML layout is having so many advantages, so why GUI programming through XML is still uncommon in GUI desktop application development?

Comment: These advantages are Android specific, not other toolkits.

Comment: Hi Roman! How do you handle a project when there are lot of files in xml? Because any change on these files, take ages in Eclipse to make effect on java files :(

Comment: I always felt supporting landscape mode is actually a gimmick. At best, okay, UI works in landscape mode, now what? A tremendous amount of effort spent for virtually no gain, while at the same time, developer now has to worry about rotating device causing Activity to recreate itself leading to in progress network request issues (in the middle of uploading an image/video? goodbye!)

Answer (score 8):

> If GUI programming through XML is really a good stuff, why it still hasn't become a common practice among GUI desktop application developers?

- .NET development uses XAML, which is XML
- Flex development, for Web and desktop via AIR, which is XML
- XUL development is XML
- There are [~20 XML bindings for Swing and SWT](http://java-source.net/open-source/xml-user-interface-toolkits)

Considering that .NET development alone probably exceeds all other desktop GUI development combined, I would argue that it has "become a common practice among GUI desktop application developers".

Moreover, using XML for GUIs is one facet of the larger "declarative UI" trend, which has many non-XML forms, such as the JSON-ish QML for Qt. AFAICT, all major GUI development is moving to incorporate such declarative markup in one form or fashion.

Comment: I know there are a lot XML binding for GUI projects. But, are they widely adopt? Can you give an example of famous Java GUI application which is using XML GUI binding?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng JavaFX

Answer (score 1):

As i think you are from the Java Swing background so may be you consider the programmatically creating layout easy task. But there are many reasons that you can think of XML strategy:

1) XML layout design is easy to understand as well keep application user interface seperate from the application code.

2) There ary many devices in the market having diffirent-diffrent display sizes and Android provides an easier task to create UI  for all using XML and keeping them seperate.

3) Also if you want to develop an multilingual application then XML is the best one.

**Bottom line:**

Only use the Java code for layout if you really need otherwise you have still best option XML.

Answer (score 1):

Think of creating a UI using HTML/CSS. I always find that handy as compared to Swing. And I believe, its not just me, but other folks too think in the same way i.e. [Jelly Swing](http://commons.apache.org/jelly/libs/swing/index.html).

Comment: I guess you obtain "Jelly Swing" by just merely Googling? As it seems to be a dead project. See its web page. (Last published: Apr 5, 2006)

Comment: @Yan Cheng: I knew this project since 2008, yes it late as well. But I didn't recommend it. I am just saying that its not a very alien idea, to do RCP using CSS kinda thing, and this actually has some implementation, no matter if stale.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one thing, it allows you to use GUI builders (like the eclipse-powered builder Google provides).

It also helps you separate your business logic from your display logic.

Probably, though, you're just really good at Swing code, and you've forgotten how long it took to build up those skills. :)

Comment: I don't really feel the pain of using Java Swing code to generate GUI, as my favorite NetBeans help to generate all the robust code. I just wondering, why don't Eclipse helps us to generate all the Java code as well, instead of generate the code in XML format.

Comment: @Yan: Beside being a fan and user of Netbeans, I would say, "Eclipse has several plugins to do that". But those might not be as good as Netbeans. Plus, Netbeans Platform is amazing, indeed.

Comment: There's nothing stopping the developer from creating a self contained custom view class that extends `RelativeLayout`, in a separate file, create an instance of this custom view in the `Activity` and set the custom view as the contentView. He/she doesn't have to shove the UI setup code inside the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say, either ways can work well if developer is skilled. 
However, I think we have to consider how this work in a team. I agree with tangentstorm. In this way, we can easy to decouple UI developer and app developer. In a team, ppl can only focus what they are doing.

Comment: UI developer? You mean the graphic designer? If so, I hear this argument before and from working in team environment with graphic designers and programmers, do you honestly expect the graphic designer to be able to install the development tools, setup all their IDE configurations, download all the dependencies from package managers, know how to use the IDE and then finally, dig through all the right menus to find that property `textCursorDrawable` for example? That's expecting graphic designer to be programmer just to make edits. How about expecting him to commit his changes to git? *faints*

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts:

- a nice way to take care of my GUI plumbing.
- whenever I need to experiment with  GUI dimensional values, code doesn't need recompilation
- XML Layouts are usually very easy to understand - initial GUI development becomes simplistic

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you should consider is that performance of creating your **UI dynamically** in your code has **better performance in android**. *Telegram* has so good performance also uses dynamic UI.
Also, you can check [article](https://medium.com/@abduazizkayumov/android-ui-xml-inflation-vs-dynamic-views-380ad5e1fae5) about dynamic and XML in performance in android that dynamic always has better performance.
But it's obvious that **dynamic UI** is much harder than **XML**.