# What is the advantage of using xml for layout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've been through a few tutorials etc and have found that I can acheive the same results defining all of my UI components in code.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("hello");
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.addView(tv);
    setContentView(ll);
}
```

is the equivalent of

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

+

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello"/>
```

What are the performance/maintainability benefits of using XML for this?

If a programmer prefers to use code over XML what extra considerations should be made?

Comment: apologies for the kind of duplicate question (as pointed out by Yan) .. i did do a search but came up with nothing relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What are the maintainability benefits of using XML for this?

1. Separation of logic from presentation.  This does help on larger projects when you need to refactor some code.  If it is tightly coupled to the UI this job can become time consuming very easily if much of the presentation logic is in code.
2. The structure of XML correlates nicely to the structure of a user interface, i.e., a tree like structure.

> What are the performance benefits of using XML for this?

That all depends on the implementation I suppose.  I doubt there are any appreciable performance differences, but I honestly don't know enough to say definitively what they may be.

Comment: actually XML has worse performance, because it first needs to be parsed on the device first: see [Anko Why DSL](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko#why-dsl). But I guess this should not make a big difference for most projects.

Answer (score 4):

You may refer to [Why using XML to create GUI is a good practice in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087628/why-using-xml-to-create-gui-is-a-good-practice-in-android).

For me, I feel this is more like personal taste. I came from Java Swing background. When I am doing desktop app development, I prefer to create GUI programmatic.

However, when comes to Android development, I will stick to XML based GUI development, although I favour to use code instead of XML.

**This is because, I tend to follow the majority favoured coding style and mythology, which makes me easy to get technical support and tutorials.**

Comment: How does using an XML layout mean that you are not using OO constructs?  These are all objects underneath the XML, I don't see the difference.

Comment: When I say OO, I mean `Label l = new Label()`

Comment: @Yan you mean programmatic, not OOP.

Answer (score 2):

The XML layout gets converted to Java code when compiled, so performance should be the same. I prefer using XML since a lot of documentation and tutorials make use of it; it's the Android way of writing out UI. Also, XML tends to be easier to reuse.

Answer (score 2):

The XML files are integrated into the resource framework, this mean that you can easily specify different layouts for different screen sizes (and densities, languages,...) .  This is important in android because of the diversity of devices.

You can of course to this programmatically but you will add a lot of unnessecary code bloat and you app will likely be harder to maintain.

The state of the layout XML editor is a problem at the moment, but announcements/demonstrations were made at google IO that significant improvements are on the way... cant wait.