# why are xml files used in Android and what functionality they provide.

Tags: android, android-xml

In my college I came to learn that XML is used to transport and store data, with support of HTML the dynamic data can be displayed , I am just curious how we design an XML in case of android and what is the connection and how it came into being. I want to learn more in this regard, insight required, tutorials if any!!

Comment: Refer to the following posts for some good explanation : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645468/why-is-xml-used-for-the-creation-of-ui-layouts-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087628/why-using-xml-to-create-gui-is-a-good-practice-in-android

Answer (score 4):

In android, there are several xml files used for sveral different purposes,

### Layout xml

It is used to define the actual User interface of your application. It holds all the elements or the tools that you want to use in your application. Like the Text Views, buttons and other UI elements.

### Manifest xml

This xml is used to define all the components of your application. It includes the names of your packages, your classes(Activities), services, receivers and the permissions that your application needs. For more about Manifest xml, refer to the [Android Manifest xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

### Strings xml

This xml file is used to replace the Hard coded strings with a single string, like you can replace **"Welcome to my application"** with **"Welcome"** string and you can refer to that string with **Welcome** string throught your application. for more about strings.xml file , refer to [strings xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

### Styles xml

This xml is used to define different styles and looks for the User Interface of application. for more info about it, refer to [styles xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html)

### Drawable xmls

These are the xml files that are used to provide various graphics to the elements of application. for more info about thses, refer to [Drawable resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)